# How to use params in a Sinatra controller

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to write Sinatra in Rails style:

```
#in app.rb
 get '/' do 
   # params request and response are accessible here
   SomeController.new.some_method
 end
```

I'm not able to access `params`, `request` or `response` in the controller:

```
  class SomeController < Sinatra::Base
    def some_method
      #params are nil here
   end
  end
```

I can do it by passing as an argument from `app.rb` but I want it to behave like Rails.

Comment: Does your `app.rb` do a `require` on the file defining `SomeController`?

Comment: Yes `app.rb` has a `require SomeControler`  the control to going to controller but params are `nil` downthere

Comment: In Rails `params` are defined in `ActionController`. Do you have a Rails example where you can access your `params` from outside of your controller?

Comment: No outside controller params are not defined but in this case, my controller is also inheriting from `Sinatra::Base` in the same way  the `get`  method in `app.rb`  does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is make a base controller which accepts the params/request/response as initialization parameters:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'byebug'

class BaseController
  attr_reader :params, :request, :response
  def initialize(sinatra_app)
    @params   = sinatra_app.params
    @request  = sinatra_app.request
    @response = sinatra_app.response
  end
end

class SomeController < BaseController
  def some_method
    {
      params:   params.class.name,
      request:  request.class.name,
      response: response.class.name,
    }.to_json
  end
end

get '/' do
  SomeController.new(self).some_method
end
```

Then testing:

```
$ curl localhost:4567
```

The response is:

```
{
  "params":"Sinatra::IndifferentHash",
  "request":"Sinatra::Request",
  "response":"Sinatra::Response"
}
```

Showing that all 3 variables are available from the current context

Comment: `BaseController` has to inherit from `Sinatra::Base`

Comment: @ashwintastic why?

Comment: Not sure how can I render views from the controller?

Comment: @ashwintastic if you changed the base controller to store a reference to `sinatra_app`, you could call `render` on that

Comment: I have achieved it by inheriting from `Sinatra::Base`.